# Show Pascal triangle properties

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove two pascal triangle properties:

1)  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{k}=\binom{p+n+1}{n}$

2) $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{p}=\binom{n+1}{p+1}$

I need some advice on how to approach to this kind of summatorial problems involving binomial coefficients.

Comment: Induction  works for the two equalities.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I know induction, and i tried it. I need a hint at less.

Comment: check out formula 8 (with proof) at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{k}=\binom{p+n+1}{n}$$
then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{p+k}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{k}+\binom{p+n+1}{n+1}=$$
$$=\binom{p+n+1}{n}+\binom{p+n+1}{n+1}=\binom{p+(n+1)+1}{(n+1)}$$
We use Pascal identity
$$\binom{m}{k}+\binom{m}{k-1}=\binom{m+1}{k}$$
Similarly for second identity
If$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{p}=\binom{n+1}{p+1}$$
then$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{k}{p}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{p}+\binom{n+1}{p}=$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{p+1}+\binom{n+1}{p}=\binom{(n+1)+1}{p+1}$$

Comment: The pascal identity is some kind of "universal hint" for this kind of equalities?. I ask this because it seems it is always used for this proofs.

Comment: It's a good identity to know if you are doing combinatorics or probability.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using negative binomial coefficients:
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-n}{k}
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\cdots(-n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

Question 1: Applying $(1)$ twice and using [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{p+k}{k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{p+k}{k}\binom{n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{-p-1}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-1}{n-k}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{-p-2}{n}\\
&=\binom{n+p+1}{n}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

Question 2: Similarly
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{p}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{p}\binom{n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{k-p}\binom{n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-p}\binom{-p-1}{k-p}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-1}{n-k}\\
&=(-1)^{n-p}\binom{-p-2}{n-p}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{n-p}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{p+1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Wow, really good.

Answer (score 1):

**2) Hint:** Since $\binom{p}{p}=1=\binom{p+1}{p+1}$

$\sum_{k=p}^{n}\binom{k}{p}=\binom{p}{p}+\binom{p+1}{p}+\binom{p+2}{p}+\dots+\binom{n}{p}$

$\Rightarrow\sum_{k=p}^{n}\binom{k}{p}=\underbrace{\binom{p+1}{p+1}+\binom{p+1}{p}}+\binom{p+2}{p}+\dots+\binom{n}{p}$

$\Rightarrow\sum_{k=p}^{n}\binom{k}{p}\,\,\,\,=\,\,\,\,\binom{p+2}{p+1}+\binom{p+2}{p}+\dots+\binom{n}{p}$

Answer (score 1):

I like to add a **combinatorial proof**, to these nice answers.

Note that we can write the first identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{k}=\binom{p+n+1}{n}$ as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{p}=\binom{p+n+1}{p+1}. \tag{*}$$
To prove it consider a $(p+n+1)$-element set $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p,x_{p+1},x_{p+2},\dots,x_{p+n+1}\}$. The **RHS** of $(*)$ is the number of $(p+1)$-element subsets of $X$. What about the **LHS**? Let us expand the **LHS**,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p+k}{p}=\binom{p}{p}+\binom{p+1}{p}+\binom{p+2}{p}+\cdots+\binom{p+n+1}{p}\tag{**}$$
It seems we have $(n+1)$ cases: selecting $p$ elements from a $p$-element set, selecting $p$ elements from a $(p+1)$-element set, $\dots$, and at the end selecting $p$ elements from a $(p+n)$-element set. But how on earth these cases can be related to the **RHS**, i.e. selecting $(p+1)$ elements from the $(p+n+1)$-element set $X$ ?! Here's how: since we want to select $(p+1)$ elements from $X$, so at least one of these $x_{p+1},x_{p+2},\dots,x_{p+n+1}$ will be selected and we have the following cases,

**Case 1:** Select $x_{p+1}$ and then $p$ elements from
$$\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p\};$$
**Case 2:** Select $x_{p+2}$ and then $p$ elements from
$$\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p,x_{p+1}\};$$
**Case 3:** Select $x_{p+3}$ and then $p$ elements from
$$\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p,x_{p+1},x_{p+2}\};$$
$\vdots$

**Case n+1:** Select $x_{p+n+1}$ and then $p$ elements from
$$\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p,x_{p+1},\dots,x_{p+n}\};$$

Now by addition principle the number of ways to select $(p+1)$ elements from $X$ is
$$\binom{p}{p}+\binom{p+1}{p}+\binom{p+2}{p}+\cdots+\binom{p+n+1}{p}$$
and it's the **LHS**, so we have $(*)$.

---

I know it seems long! But, I believe it's worthy and this kind of proof gives you some visions to construct new identities, it lets you to feel the identity, things that you can not find in an algebraic proof.